# Async loading data from firebase to HTML page with yandex map embedded

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, yandex-maps

I'm trying to retrieve data from firebase to html page with yandex map embedded. All is fine, data comes, but problem is that data comes **after** the map is rendered, so any markers are showing

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.1.0/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&mode=debug"></script>
  <!-- connect to firebase and fetch data from there -->
  <script src="./js/firebase.js"></script>
  <!-- load array from file-->
  <!-- <script src="./js/arr.js"></script> -->  
    <title>Page Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>  
  <!-- map here -->
  <div id="map" style="width:800px; height:600px"></div>      
  <!-- markers go into map -->
  <script src="./js/map.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

firebase.js

```
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
 ...
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var firebaseDB = firebase.database();
var arr = []

firebaseDB.ref('arr').once('value')
.then((snap) => {
  snap.forEach((item) => {
    arr.push({
      id: item.key,
      ...item.val() 
    })
    console.log('item pushed to arr'); //fires after map rendered
  })
  console.log('arr', arr); // full of data , but too late
})
```

map.js

```
ymaps.ready(init);
var myMap; 

function init() {

myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
  center: [56.18, 56.23],
  zoom: 4,
  controls: ['routeButtonControl'],
  behaviors: ['drag']
});

var BalloonContentLayoutClass = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<h3>{{ properties.name }}</h3>');


console.log(arr) // I want it here be filled with data already, but  it is empty (( 

arr.forEach(function (m) {
  var marker = new ymaps.Placemark(
    [m.coords.lat, m.coords.lon],
    {
      name: m.name,
      address: m.address,
      phone: m.phone,
    },
    { balloonContentLayout: BalloonContentLayoutClass }
  );
  myMap.geoObjects.add(marker);
  console.log('marker added')
  });
};
```

Tried to place map's `function(init)` in firebase's `.then()` promice, with no luck.

Tried to use `async` with firebase library script loading - same luck.

When same structured data are loaded from local js file (arr.js) - all is working fine: loading, showing, shining. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure whether that's what you tried, but you would have to put `ymaps.ready(init)` into `.then()` I guess. Unless that command assigns a handler.

Comment: @Chris G Tried this, as well as put map's `function(init)` into firebase's promise . No luck ((

Comment: Move the `arr.forEach` part to a separate function and call that in your `then()`. Make sure any needed variables are in the outer scope and visible. Check your console for errors.

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/320jhmaq/

Comment: Thank U very much. Just a brilliant help. Take care ))